# Replace next N lines before a first/second/third/... match including the match

Tags: linux, awk, sed, gnu

I'm trying to comment on the next 14 lines from the first match only.

This is the text to edit:

```
...
    Text
    {
        id: userNameText
        text: userName
        color: ( hoverEnabled && hover ? colors.textHover : colors.text )
    
        font: fonts.listItemMed

        elide: Text.ElideRight

        x: itemRoot.height + 12
        y: 0

        width: itemRoot.width - itemRoot.height - 26
    }

    Text
    {
        id: userLoginText
        text: userLogin
        color: ( hoverEnabled && hover ? (userName == "" ? colors.textHover : colors.textDimmedHover ) : (userName == "" ? colors.text : colors.textDimmed ) )
        y: userName == "" ? 7 : userNameText.height * 0.8
        font: userName == "" ? fonts.listItemBig : fonts.listItemSub
        x: itemRoot.height + 12

        elide: Text.ElideRight

        width: itemRoot.width - itemRoot.height - 26
    }
}
```

I am using sed and these are the 2 closest options I have gotten.

```
sed -e '/^    Text$/ {s/^/\/\//; n; s/^/\/\//; n; s/^/\/\//; n; s/^/\/\//; n; s/^/\/\//; n; s/^/\/\//; n; s/^/\/\//; n; s/^/\/\//; n; s/^/\/\//; n; s/^/\/\//; n; s/^/\/\//; n; s/^/\/\//; n; s/^/\/\//; n; s/^/\/\//; n; s/^/\/\//;}'
```

^^^
This comment next 14 lines in both "^    Text$"

```
sed -e '0,/^    Text$/ {s/^    Text$/\/\/    Text/}'
```

^^^
And this comment only the first match, if I invert the match with "!" I can comment the rest of the file instead but is not the idea

The expected output would be:

```
...
//    Text
//    {
//        id: userNameText
//        text: userName
//        color: ( hoverEnabled && hover ? colors.textHover : colors.text )
//    
//        font: fonts.listItemMed
//
//        elide: Text.ElideRight
//
//        x: itemRoot.height + 12
//        y: 0
//
//        width: itemRoot.width - itemRoot.height - 26
//    }

    Text
    {
        id: userLoginText
        text: userLogin
        color: ( hoverEnabled && hover ? (userName == "" ? colors.textHover : colors.textDimmedHover ) : (userName == "" ? colors.text : colors.textDimmed ) )
        y: userName == "" ? 7 : userNameText.height * 0.8
        font: userName == "" ? fonts.listItemBig : fonts.listItemSub
        x: itemRoot.height + 12

        elide: Text.ElideRight

        width: itemRoot.width - itemRoot.height - 26
    }
}
```

Any way to achieve this without inserting the exact lines is welcome!

---

Thank you so much to 'potong' and 'Cole Tierney', your answers made the way for me, I don't want to copy and paste, but you gave me good patterns to follow, you are awesome!

Comment: Please edit your question in order to include also the corresponding output you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a BSD sed version (comment.sed):

```
/Text/, /}/ {
    s|^|//|
    /}/ {
        :idle
        n
        b idle
    }
}
```

The first line `/Text/, /}/` is a regex address range. Every line within that that range (inclusive) will be commented out. At the end of this range, the second `/}/`, we loop back to the `idle` label consuming the rest of the file. Otherwise the address range would also comment out the second `Text` block.

A one line version:

```
sed '/Text/, /}/ {s|^|//|; /}/ {:idle; n; b idle}}' input
```

To test:

```sh
diff expect <(sed -f comment.sed input) && echo ok
```

Comment: Nice! Your code works great, can you explain it in detail?

This is what I think it does, it finds the lines between Text and '}' and writes at the beginning '//', :idle; n; b idle; is to repeat only once, maybe? I don't know what the ',' or the second /}/ really means. I'm trying to adapt it in one line without files, thanks you are awesome!

Comment: I've added more detail to the explanation and a one line version.

Comment: Thanks, I got it after reading a couple more times, now I'm looking to skip the first range and edit the second one, if you have free time and want to help me that would be awesome, thanks for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: Sed is fun, but if you're interested in the second Text block, I would recommend `awk`. Variables will make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\s*Text/{:a;N;/^\(\s*\).*\n\1*}$/!ba;s/.*/\/\/ &/mg;:b;n;bb}' file
```

Gather up the lines from `Text` to `}`, insert `//`  before them and then read the remainder of the file.

Comment: Nice! Your code works great and in one line but it's harder to understand, can you explain it please?